# Bootstrap-select behind another div

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-select

I'm facing this problem with a Bootstrap-select (https://github.com/silviomoreto/bootstrap-select) dropdown list:
[image]

As you can see the dropdown is displayed behind the second element (the second div with green background).
This second div is created with this simple code:

```
<div class="col-md-7" style="height:100%">
    <div id="prt-form-container" class="prt-vertical-align">
    [...]
    </div>
</div>
```

`col-md-7` is a standard Bootstrap class.

The dropdown list code is:

```
<div class="btn-group bootstrap-select form-control prt-form-control open">
    <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown" title="Indica la professione" aria-expanded="true"><span class="filter-option pull-left">Indica la professione</span>&nbsp;<span class="bs-caret"><span class="caret"></span></span></button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu open" style="max-height: 178px; overflow: hidden;">
        <div class="bs-searchbox"><input type="text" class="form-control" autocomplete="off"></div>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu inner" role="menu" style="max-height: 130px; overflow-y: auto;">
        [...]
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I correctly show the dropdown list?

Comment: I think z-index issue. please you can give higher z-index in your select div.

Comment: @Jainam tried with: `<div class="btn-group bootstrap-select form-control prt-form-control open" style="z-index: 999999;">` and parent element with `position:relative` but it didn't work.

Comment: could you create fiddle?

Comment: @s.milziadi, if you are going to give an element a z-index, you will have to give it either a relative, fixed or absolute position. So maybe try: `<div class="btn-group bootstrap-select form-control prt-form-control open" style="z-index: 999999; position:relative">`